# Parse: PFObject is loaded without Attributes

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2, xcode7

I need to get some 'Kurse' (PFObjects) from the database and then I need to get the name of another PFObject which is a pointer of the 'kurs' but if I try to do this nothing happens. There is no error and the program does not break or something like that but the "test2" is not printed!

```
let user = PFUser.currentUser()

    let query = PFQuery(className: "Kurs")
    query.whereKey("stufe", equalTo: user!["stufe"])

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }
        else if let kurse = objects{
            print("kurse:", kurse)
            for kurs in kurse{
                print("kurs:", kurs)
                var gibtEsSchon = false

                if gibtEsSchon == false{
                    print("test1")


                    let fach = kurs["fach"] as! PFObject
                    print("fach", fach)
                    let name = fach["name"] as! String
                    print("test2")
                    self.daten.append(Fach(dieKurse: [kurs], name: name))
                    print("daten 3", self.daten)
                }

            }

        }
```

So the line

```
 let name = fach["name"] as! String
```

is not called.

But I think I know why: If I print("fach", fach) the result doesn't have the attribute 'name' that it should have. I think that the PFObject is not loaded completely:

**What I get:**

> fach  {
>   }

**What I want:**

> fach  {
>   name = German;
>   }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `query.includeKey("fach")` above `query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` should fix that.
From the [PFQuery class reference](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/includeKey:), `includeKey` will

> Make the query include PFObjects that have a reference stored at the provided key.